# Awkward Substitution in Sympy

Tags: python, sympy, sage

Is there a simpler way to do substitution in Sympy which is similar to Sage or Mathematica. 
In Mathematica You have something called as eliminate() which given a set of equations you can ask it to eliminate certain variables.
In Sage you need to be more hands on with it but its still more or less similar to Mathematica. 
In Sympy comparatively its more awkward to do substitution.

In the screenshot the red arrows show what i am talking about. The white Arrow is the method i think would be more appropriate.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQHzd.jpg]

edit 1: here is a link to the function in mathematica http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Eliminate.html

Comment: If you use the `latex` function in SymPy most if that escaping you are doing will be done for you.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not understanding what you're asking. Can you show the same example for SymPy and Sage or Mathematica?

Comment: Sure, lets say you have two equations. `eq1 = x == y`  `eq2 = x == 5`  if you want to substitute `eq2` in `eq1` in sage you would just do `ans = eq1.sub(eq2)`. In Sympy its not as straigtforward. Basically you cannot have expressions such as :  `eq1 = x == y` rather you just do `x = y` or `eq1 = x - y`. this doesnt help when you want to pass in `eq2 = x - 5` as a substitution since sympy doesnt know you want to get rid of `x`, rather you need to pass in `{x:5}` which is fine for small equations but if you have a lot of variables it becames tedious compared to the sage/mathematica way

Comment: There are a few ways this could be done, but I'm not sure what the cleanest is. I did open https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/2720 for `eliminate()`.

Comment: hey thanks ! I think someone already was talking about this somewhere in google threads/mailing list.

Answer (score 4):

You can have equations (actually Equality object) in SymPy:

```
>>> eq1=Eq(x,y);eq2=Eq(x,5)
```

But you are right, subs doesn't guess everything for you. It looks like Sage assumes that if a variable is isolated on one side of an equation, that is the variable to be replaced. But there is no guarantee that you will always conveniently have the desired variable isolated. It's not hard to use solve to give you the desired variable isolated:

```
>>> solve(eq2,x,dict=1)
[{x:5}]
```

And then that can be substituted into the equation from which you want to eliminate that variable.

```
>>> eq1.subs(solve(eq2,x,dict=1)[0])
5=y
```

Use of the "exclude" keyword doesn't presently behave quite as I would expect; perhaps it should act in an elimination sense:

```
>>> solve((eq1,eq2), exclude=(x,))
{y:x}
```

Comment: As I recall, the ability to use Eq with subs was discussed at some point and rejected.

Comment: There is a first draft of a function that makes this more automated [here](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/2720). (Look for the URL of this page on that page.)

Answer (score 0):

Following up on the above comments and https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/14741, one way to do the above in Sympy would be:

```
from sympy import Eq, var
var('P, F, K, M, E0, E1, E2, E3, E4')
a = Eq(E1, (E0 + P - F)*K - M)
b = Eq(E2, (E1 + P - F)*K - M)
c = Eq(E3, (E2 + P - F)*K - M)
d = Eq(E4, (E3 + P - F)*K - M - F)
d.subs(*c.args).subs(*b.args).subs(*a.args)
```